# Calculating the average marks of each test and grading of the student

Tags: java

My program has some problem as it cannot calculate the average marks in each test, and also the student average marks and grade.

Can somebody help me to correct my code?As I need to hand-in the assignment on Wednesday.And also help me to check the other code in there has mistake.

Thanks a lot.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Variables for input name and output name
    String nameInp = "";
    String nameOut = "";

    // Arrays to store marks of 5 tests of each student
    double [] tests = new double[5];

    // Arrays to store average and sum of the 5 tests
    double[] testAvg = new double[5];
    double[] testSum = new double[5];

    // Arrays to store max and min of the 5 tests
    double[] max = new double[5];
    double[] min = new double[5];

    // Arrays to store the name of students who got max or min
    // in the 5 tests
    String[] nameMax = new String[5];
    String[] nameMin = new String[5];

    // Number of students
    int studCount = 0;

    // Average and grade of the 5 tests of each students
    double studAverage;
    String studGrade;

    // Scanner for reading file
    Scanner scf = new Scanner(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                              "/src/student_marks.txt"));

    // Set the max and min of the 5 tests
    // to Double's min and max respectively
    double max_tests = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double min_tests = Double.MIN_VALUE;



    // Print output heading
    System.out.println("Student Name Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Average Grade");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");

    // While there are more data to read from the input file
    while (scf.hasNext()) {


      // Increment number of students
        int count;
        count++;

      // Read a student name 
      nameInp = scf.next();

      // Replace the "_" in the name with a " "
      nameOut = nameInp.replaceAll("_", " ");

      // For each student, calculate the sum of the test marks,
      // record the max and min marks of each test and
      tests[5] = scf.nextDouble();
      testSum[5] += tests[5];

      if (tests[5] > max_tests) {
            max_tests = tests[5];
      }
      if (tests[5] < min_tests) {
            min_tests = tests[5];
      }

      // record the name of studunts scoring those max and min marks

      if (tests[5] > max_tests) {
            max_tests = tests[5];
            nameMax[5] = nameOut;
        }
        if (tests[5] < min_tests) {
            min_tests = tests[5];
            nameMin[5] = nameOut;
        }



      // Call the computeStudAvg method to calculate the average marks
      // of each student
        studAverage = computeStudAvg( testAvg );



      // Call the computeStudGrade to get the grade of each student
        studGrade = computeStudGrade(  );


      // Print the tests, average and grade of each student 
      System.out.printf("%-10s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n", nameOut, tests[1], tests[2], tests[3], tests[4], tests[5], studGrade);


    } // end while more students


    // Calculate the average marks of each of the 5 tests
       testAvg[5] = testSum[5] / 5;




    // Print the average of each test
       System.out.printf("Test Average:          ", testAvg[1], testAvg[2], testAvg[3], testAvg[4], testAvg[5]);



    // Print the max marks, min marks and names of students 
    System.out.println("Test      Max--Student                 Min-Student                ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("Test1" + max[1] , nameMax[1] , min[1] , nameMin[1]);
    System.out.printf("Test2" + max[2] , nameMax[2] , min[2] , nameMin[2]);
    System.out.printf("Test3" + max[3] , nameMax[3] , min[3] , nameMin[3]);
    System.out.printf("Test4" + max[4] , nameMax[4] , min[4] , nameMin[4]);
    System.out.printf("Test5" + max[5] , nameMax[5] , min[5] , nameMin[5]);


    System.out.println();
    scf.close();
  }




// Method to compute and return the average mark of the 5 tests for each student 
  public static double computeStudAvg(double[] testSum) {
    return (testSum[5] / 5 );
  }

  // Method to compute and return the grade of each student
  public static String computeStudGrade(double[] studAvg ) {
      if ( average >=75 ) {
        return "A";
      } else if ( average >= 65 ) {
        return "B";
      } else if ( average >= 50 ) {
        return "C";
      } else if ( average >= 40 ) {
        return "D";
      } else
        return "F"; 
      }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't an assignment solution center. At least you should specify exactly what your program should do.

Comment: Looks like there are couple of problems in your code. `int count;` this needs to be declared outside loop. You haven't used indexes properly instead hard coded while accessing array elements. Some parts have compilation issues that you need to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is to calculate min and max.  
Reverse the assignments in these lines:

```
double max_tests = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double min_tests = Double.MIN_VALUE;
```

should be:

```
double max_tests = Double.MIN_VALUE;
double min_tests = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

When you compare a grade to `min_tests` if it had the value of `Double.MIN_VALUE` the comparison would always fail, because there is no grade less than `Double.MIN_VALUE`.